# Spring Boot , Swagger - Unable to render this definition

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

Spring boot

In my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java' // jar not work with JSP
    //id 'war' // to use JSP
}

group = 'com.myproject'
version = '1.0.2'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

processResources {
    filesMatching('application.yml') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0')
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0')
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2'
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

here application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: debug

# for Spring Actuator
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: beans, env, info, health, metrics

server:
  port: 8090
  connection-timeout: 30000

spring:
  application:
    name: E-shop
    version: ${version}
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./db/eshop.h2.db
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
    enabled: true
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    suffix: .html
  h2: # default db. Open web page to H2 db -> http://localhost:8090/h2-console
    console:
      enabled: true
  http:
    converters:
      preferred-json-mapper: gson
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
      suffix: .jsp
```

Here my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource; // get by Spring

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Here, you are making the public directory on the classpath root available without authentication (e..g. for css files)
                .antMatchers("/public/**", "/registration.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> new DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/index"))
                .failureUrl("/login-error.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll();
    }

    // login by user from db
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, active FROM usr WHERE username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT u.username, ur.role FROM usr u INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON u.id = ur.user_id WHERE u.username=?");
    }
```

In my application:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import java.util.Date;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableSwagger2
public class EshopApplication {
```

Here my swagger config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

But when I try to start Swagger on address:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8090/swagger-ui.html
```

I get error:

```
Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the swagger configuration?

Comment: @Jens I was updated my post.

Comment: silly suggestion but maybe change the version from 2.9.2 to 2.0?

Comment: Not help. Project is not started with 2.0.1.

Comment: Can you share please complete `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Valijon I was updated my post.

Comment: Without `application.yml` (share it too), it works for me: `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` (First I need to login because of spring security)

Comment: @Valijon I first success login and only after that I try to open swagger. I was updated my post.

Comment: Do you customize `swagger-ui.html` ? Or it returns the default implementation. Also, is it possible to share your project to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Valijon No, I has no custom swagger-ui.html. I try to use default  implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218167/discussion-between-valijon-and-a-subscriber).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following bean to your code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem. In my case, the problem was some mistake in serialization using jackson X gson.
What I did: I added a converter to gson in the Swagger config class.

```
@Bean
public GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter() {
    GsonHttpMessageConverter converter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setGson(gson());
    return converter;
}

private Gson gson() {
    final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Json.class, new SpringfoxJsonToGsonAdapter());
    return builder.create();
}

public class SpringfoxJsonToGsonAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Json> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Json json, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return JsonParser.parseString(json.value());
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the import for the "Json" class? Can you include all of the imports as well?

Answer (score 0):

Press 'F12' in your browser, make sure every swagger request reponses correctly. Maybe /v2/api-docs is intercepted by SpringSecurity.